# Cannot update mySQL with Servlet and JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, sql-update

My update wont go through, as it does not recognize my Pelaajaid (Player id). I'm desperate with it, and can not figure out why it doesn't work.

**THE ERROR**  https://gyazo.com/471fc2464e54b7bef534e02ab6eaf774

My Update servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.dao.PelaajaDAO;
import model.Pelaaja;

@WebServlet("/muokkaa-pelaajaa")

public class MuokkaaPelaajaaServlet extends HttpServlet {






        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/muokkaa.jsp").forward(request, response);
            String pelaajaidStr = request.getParameter("pelaajaid");
            int pelaajaid = Integer.parseInt(pelaajaidStr);
        }


            protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    

                try {


                String nimi = request.getParameter("nimi");
                String pelipaikka = request.getParameter("pelipaikka");
                String palkka = request.getParameter("ika");
                String ika = request.getParameter("ika");


                String pelaajaidStr = request.getParameter("pelaajaid");
                int pelaajaid = Integer.parseInt(pelaajaidStr);

                Pelaaja pelaaja = new Pelaaja();
                pelaaja.setPelaajaid(pelaajaid);
                pelaaja.setNimi(nimi);
                pelaaja.setPelipaikka(pelipaikka);
                pelaaja.setPalkka(palkka);
                pelaaja.setIka(ika);




                PelaajaDAO pelaajadao = new PelaajaDAO();

                pelaajadao.updatePelaaja(pelaaja, pelaajaid);

                response.sendRedirect("/listaa-pelaajat");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();    
        request.setAttribute("viesti", "Sovelluksessa tapahtui virhe");
        // servlet kutsuu jsp:tä
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/tapahtumaraportti.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
    }


}
```

Here is my JSP for editing (it gets the pelaajaid via url)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
     <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tietojen muokkaus</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Muokkaa Pelaajaa ja Nykyiset pelaajat</h1>

<form action="/muokkaa-pelaajaa" method="post">

Nimi: <input type="text" name="nimi" />
Pelipaikka: <input type="text" name="pelipaikka" />
Palkka: <input type="text" name="palkka" />
Ika: <input type="text" name="ika" />


<input type="submit" value="Valmis" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/listaa-pelaajat'" />

<input type="button" value="Peruuta" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/listaa-pelaajat'">

</body>
</html>
```

It gets the Pelaajaid via the url, and foreso should recognize it..?

```
<td><a href="/muokkaa-pelaajaa?pelaajaid=<c:out value='${pelaaja.pelaajaid}'/>">Muokkaa</a></td>'
```

I'm a starter, and can't figure this out on my own. Any help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't upload images of code/error, please post them in OP.

Comment: Thank you @ngShravil.py :) I will later on

Comment: You are getting that error in doPost method here `Integer.parseInt(pelaajaidStr)` because  `pelaajaidStr` is null and `<form>` doesn't have any input with name `pelaajaidStr` .